# Autocomplete in datagrid results in duplicate value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete, datatable, weblogic12c

We have a `DataTable` with `editMode="cell"`. The autocomplete celleditor works okay when the user actually selects something, but if he moves to another cell without doing anything, the value displayed in the previous cell is duplicated. I do not know if this is the expected behaviour, but even though no selection happened after the cell editor is gone the cell displays the duplicated value of whatever value autocomplete displayed. Why would the value of the cell editor be assigned to the cell when no editing took place?

Leslie

PrimeFaces 3.5; Weblogic 12c

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is it possible for you to provide some code (of what you've tried) so it would be easier for people to answer your question?

Comment: Hi, it is not easy at all.This project is unusual in many ways.That is why I have tried to focus on the part where understanding how PF works might help.The PF components are bound to a somewhat complex DTO implementing runtime generics behaviour.Debugging proves that there is no problem with the data.Plus there is no communication to the server from the point where the autocomplete is displayed.So whatever happens after that happens within the PF components.If it was possible to stop autocomplete assigning its value to the cell it belongs to when there is no change it would solve the problem.

Comment: Probably the same issue : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30532